# How to define a command with lstlist code as argument

Tags: macros, listings

I want to implement a command like these:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\newcommand{\oneCode}[1]{
   \begin{lstlisting}
   #1
   \end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}

\oneCode{#$duihnlv/}

\end{document}
```

It seems, that *lstlisting* interpretes the argument `#1` as code not as argument.

How to force *lstlisting* to take `#1` as argument?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Use the commands provided by `listings` to create new envrionments or inline commands. Your command currently looks like `\lstinline`.

Comment: It becomes more complex later on. This is only the example for this question.

Comment: you can not, in general, use any verbatim command (including listings) in the argument of another command.

Comment: Could you please explain at which point the commands provided by listings aren't sufficient?

Comment: There is nothing insufficient. It is only for formatting / pre-defining minipages. There are some hundreds code snippets which shall displayed always in the same format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define new inline versions of `\lstinline` like this. The important point is not to use a (mandatory) argument so that \lstinline can do its own magic.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}


\newcommand\oneCode{\lstinline[basicstyle=\color{green}\sffamily]}
\begin{document}

\oneCode{#$duihnlv/}

\end{document}
```

[image]